# Minify JavaScript code containing Jinja2 expressions with the Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, python, json, jinja2, google-closure-compiler

I pass a JSON-encoded dictionary from Python 3 to Jinja2 template and assign it to a JavaScript variable. My template is as follows

```html
<script>
    var a = {{ json_dict }}; // is rendered as `var a = {"key": "value"};`
</script>
```

This works as expected, but  I'd like to minify JavaScript code containing [Jinja2 expressions](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#expressions) using [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), which currently throws predictable errors like

```js
JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. '}' expected at line 2 character 9
var a = {{ json_dict }};
```

What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrap it in an eval or equivalent.

```
a = eval('({{json_dict}})')
```